# Connecting to sql server named instance using gorm erroring out with invalid character "\\" in host name

Tags: sql-server, go, go-gorm

I am trying to connect to a locally running sql server developer instance from golang using gorm library using the below connection string

"sqlserver://trusted_connection=yes@localhost\MSSQLSERVER02:1443?database=operationsdb"

but getting the below error

parse sqlserver://trusted_connection=yes@US71DX930J\MSSQLSERVER02:1443?database=operationsdb: invalid character "\" in host name

Comment: try `localhost/MSSQLSERVER02` instead of `localhost\MSSQLSERVER02`

Comment: awesome that worked thanks @Burak Serdar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is the Go MSSQL driver you're talking about, try using " / " for the named instance instead of a " \ " backslash:

"sqlserver://trusted_connection=yes@localhost/MSSQLSERVER02:1443?database=operationsdb"

https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/blob/master/README.md